# change the date format ,column is of text data type

Tags: postgresql, datetime, date-formatting

i have a table with column app_date (data type is text).i want to convert it to different format.Below are the examples

```
app_date 

Sep-17   
Jan-18  
Jun-16
```

i want to convert it as

```
 new_app_date

 Sep2017
 Jan2018
 Jun2016
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? We are delighted to help you but you have to know that we aren't here to make your homework and, IMO it looks like that: "I have... Below are the examples... I want to...". Nothing about "I tried this but I had this problem" or anything.

Comment: i got the error invalid date format .later realized the column data type is "text" .Fixed the data type and it got  worked.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`replace():`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)

```
update my_table
set app_date = replace(app_date, '-', '20')
returning app_date
```

Comment: thanks.but i have like million records and update really takes time.Is there any other way to do this.

Comment: There are no good alternatives if the change should be persistent. You can however casually use `replace()` in your selects.